# LocalizedStrings with Ids starting with disclaimer_* not working in custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to add a custom link in the sign-up page with StringIds 'disclaimer_' but getting validation errors during upload of custom policy.
[Validation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQSey.png)

Tried adding these strings to api.localaccountsignup.en, api.signuporsignin.en. The doc says we can add these to sign-up or self asserted page.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids#sign-up-and-self-asserted-pages-user-interface-elements

```
<LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="disclaimer_msg_intro">text</LocalizedString>
<LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="disclaimer_link_1_text">Privacy Statement</LocalizedString>
<LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="disclaimer_link_1_url">url</LocalizedString>
```

Answer (score 0):

That error message means there is something wrong with the XML.

Use an XML parser to check the format.

What is the format of your custom link?

Comment: it does not work when I add the strings for 'api.localaccountsignup.en' or 'api.signuporsignin.en'. The same set of strings work for 'phoneSingin.en'.  As per the doc, we should be able to add it to signupsignin. The URL I'm trying is valid and so is the text.